# Finding Path in AR Circumstances

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, path-finding, google-project-tango, android-augmented-reality

I want to instantiate a Path Between the current position of the camera and an AR object placed in the scene. The Path should avoid entering walls. I have thought about finding the floor and then find the tango point clouds which are at the same height as the floor and then somehow create a path which connects those point clouds until he reaches the proximity of the AR object.

Have anyone tried to achieve this kind of behaviour before and if so how they managed to achieve it?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I've done it. While my app is in Learning Mode and the user is moving around the camera to learn the area and to place different markers on objects, I spawn cubes at Camera positions after a certain distance. Then with the aid of all those spawned cubes I built a graph and then applied a Dijkstra path finding algorithm in the graph. I left my solution in case someone will encounter the same functionality and will have no idea about how to implement it.